# How to use signal in PyQt5 ScatterPlot

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a point cloud in which I click on a point and it returns me the position, x, y, z of that point.

And as we can see in the documentation, there is a signal to perform this action: https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/scatterplotitem.html

I therefore wrote the following code, knowing that I already had my point cloud beforehand.

```
self.position =gl.GLScatterPlotItem(pos=self.pos)
self.position.sigClicked.connect(self.clicked())        
self.graphtroisd.addItem(self.position)
```

With an additionnal fonction:

```
def clicked(self, points):
    print("points : " + points)
```

However I run into the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'GLScatterPlotItem' object has no attribute 'sigClicked'
```

Comment: You don't need to call the function `self.position.sigClicked.connect(self.clicked)`

Comment: I tried with and without the "()" and it didn't change anything, the error remains the same

Answer (score 0):

`GLScatterPlotItem` and `ScatterPlotItem` are different classes altogether. Looks like you're trying to use a signal from `ScatterPlotItem` with a `GLScatterPlotItem` object.

See the documentation differences here:

https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/scatterplotitem.html
https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3dgraphics/glscatterplotitem.html

Notice that in `GLScatterPlotItem`, no such signal exists.

Comment: it is therefore impossible to be able to click on a data in a 3D graph? x_x

Comment: @Pierre-yvesIcdcChaboche It's not impossible at all. It's very possible. You'll have to implement ray-tracing by creating an orthogonal 2D projection and finding where the screen mouse coordinate intersects the 3D plane. Or find a different suitable library that has the feature you want built-in.